# Sublime Text Package Control search not work properly

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, package-control

Have trouble with *Sublime Text 3* and *Package Control*. Can't find some packages through search (some plugins finds, some not), for example *Color Picker* plugin (https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/ColorPicker). Tried to reinstall *Package Control* and re-add repository but without results.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that you already installed `ColorPicker` at some point, and this is the reason it's not showing up in the searches you do via the Command Palette, such as using *`Package Control: Install Package`*. Go to **`Preferences -> Package Settings -> Package Control -> Settings-User`** and check the list of currently-installed packages to ensure it's not already listed there. If for some reason it's there, but not installed, delete it, restart Sublime, then try your search again, and it should show up.

Comment: Thanks. First I delete from settings like you suggest and restart ST. But no effect with search. Then I remove it via package control and search started working. (Maybe PackageControl have another place for storing data about installed packages)

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of Sublime Text 3, the above mentioned commands not available.
It is now available under `Preferences -> Package Control Settings - User`.