# Can not install Colorsublime via Package Control - Sublimetext 2

Tags: sublimetext2

I tried using the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24348116/sublime-text-package-control-search-not-work-properly) but I could not get it to work. I also see that the Colorsublime plugin is not installed so it should show up when I do a search for it via Package Control. Puzzled.

Installed plugins: http://grab.by/DBDi

Many thanks,
Houston

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Colorsublime) for Colorsublime, you'll see that it only works with Sublime Text 3.